# Change extension of selected files with CMD

Tags: cmd, zip, batch-processing, file-extension, rar

I have a folder with well over 400 RAR, ZIP and 7Z files. I want to make a **bat** file that change the extensions of **selected files** in this folder as follows, RAR->CBR, ZIP->CBZ and 7Z->CB7 without renaming files **not selected**.

I have tried with:

> `ren %1 *.cbr`

and:

> `ren %~n1.rar *cbr`

but it does not work.

The **bat** file is going to be placed in the **Send To** menu.

I want, if possible, to use only cmd, as I don't know any scripting, or programming language.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[This answered your original question, which as more about "all" or multiple files.]

You can use the `FOR` loop. Type `for /?` for details.

First, try the FOR command out to make it ECHO (print) the filename. You can use this to test what you want/think it's going to do:

```
for %f in (*.rar) do echo %f
```

Then, to actually rename, you'll need something like:

```
for %f in (*.rar) do ren %f *.cbr
```

---

[Following your edit]:

If you're calling a batch file from 'Send To' or whatever, your select file should come in in parameter `%1` (and `%2`, `%3` etc if multiple). You may also be able to use `%*` for all parameters.

Try echoing it somewhere, to console or a file, to test whether you're receiving these & what's happening. Save the following as a batch file, and try it:

```
echo %1
pause
```

In a batch file, % symbols need to be doubled up (for parsing reasons). So to rename, you might try something like:

```
for %%f in (%*) do echo %%f
for %%f in (%*) do ren %%f *.cbr
```

See also: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Testing with `for %%f in (*.rar) do ren "%%f"*.cbr`and `for %%f in (*.zip) do ren "%%f" *.cbz` still affects all files of same extension, not only selected files that I drag on bat file

Comment: Yes, you asked the "rename all" question initially. Try the `%*` version further down, to see if you can pickup the selected files/ parameters you call the batch file with. You can also use `echo` to test what you're doing. _This stuff can go wrong, make sure you don't rename 400 important files wrongly by accident!_